# Enable the intl extension to use CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, plesk

Php Version : 5.6.0
Cakephp version : 3.0
Hosting Shared , plesk server

Error:

PHP Fatal error:  You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP.
 in 
G:\PleskVhosts\xxxxxxxxxxx.com\election.vipscollege.com\config\requirements.php on line 33

We got solution for that :

On windows servers, open your php.ini (which should be in Program Files/PHP), and simply uncomment the extension.
extension=php_intl.dll

But we can't access php.ini file , is there any way for enable php_intl.dll using Cakephp 3 ?

Thanks in Advance

Deepak Goud

Comment: what server are you using

Comment: godady :  plesk server

Answer (score 1):

As it stands in GoDaddy docs, you need to enable it in your initialization file. For plesk hosting, you should create `.user.ini` file in your website root and you can enable intl extension there.

Additional reading:

[GoDaddy - enable custom PHP modules](https://pl.godaddy.com/help/enable-custom-php-modules-12036)

[GoDaddy - what filename does my PHP initialization file need to use?](https://pl.godaddy.com/help/what-filename-does-my-php-initialization-file-need-to-use-8913)

Answer (score 0):

whether you can. you just have to open it with an editor like (sublime, notepad ++, etc ...). And then you unzip *** extension = php_intl.dll ***